# Typescript 1.4: Wrong syntax highlighting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

Typescript 1.4 has been released recently, providing new possibilities like unions.

I installed the new version for Visual Studio, however the syntax highlighting doesn't recognise unions:

```
var member: string|number;
```

Although it can be compiled without problems, the syntax checker hovers the definition and any usage of the variable `member`.

What do I need to update to get this working?

Comment: So any answers for us non-resharper peasants?

Comment: @JohnWeisz Use resharper!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Rather than turning off Resharper, you could configure it to ignore analysing errors in `*.ts` files. (`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Resharper Options` -> `Code Inspection` -> `Settings` -> `File Masks to Skip` -> add `*.ts`)

This way you still benefit from using Resharper for other files, and you also get the benefits of code formatting and the like for TypeScript using Resharper.

Comment: Excellent, this is a better answer than mine.

Comment: Looks like R# will fix it in 9.1 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427653

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue where Resharper was not recognizing the "const" keyword.

I fixed this by explicitly telling Resharper what version of TypeScript to use. By default it is set to "auto detection".

On the menu, go to Resharper > Options > Code Editing > TypeScript.

Change the Type Script Language Level to "1.5 (experimental)"

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue, and for me it was Resharper that was causing the problem.

If you have Resharper installed then simply disable it while working on TypeScript 1.4, at least until JetBrains releases an update with 1.4 support.

To disable Resharper:
`Tools -> Resharper -> General -> Suspend`

Comment: Good catch, that was the problem :)
Do you have any experience on how long ReShaper usually needs to get updated?

Comment: Note: For me, the suspend button was at `Tools -> Options -> ReShaprerPlatformVs12 -> Suspend`

Comment: @maja From my experience with JetBrains products they aren't too fast to release updates for such things, but I don't see any reason why this would take long. The 1.4 definition has been out for quite a while now, so I imagine that they have started working on it before the official release.

Comment: @maja Also, if you're not already using it, I suggest you try *Web Essentials for Visual Studio*.