# TypeScript 1.4 with VS 2013 Update 4 intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense, typescript1.4

I have:

- Visual Studio 2013 pro Update 4
- Web Essentials 2.5.2
- TypeScript 1.4
- Resharper 8.2.3

When I open a typescript file, syntax highlighting works fine, also tooltip on the function shows its definition. However, intellisense is not working (when I press a . near an object, it does not show properties or methods).

This is just a test project of type TypeScript Web Project. I tried to google but unable to find a solution yet. Any ideas what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many trial and error I could fix it by:

1. Removing 10.0 folder in %APPDATA%/microsoft/microsoft visual studio
2. Disabling intellisense for typescript in Resharper
3. Uninstalling Web Essentials from visual studio 2013
4. Uninstalling TypeScript 1.4
5. Reinstalling TypeScript
6. Reinstalling Web Essentials
7. Setting back Resharper settings

Only thing I can think is that it may have something to do with the order of installation of web essentials and typescript.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002810/typescript-1-4-wrong-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio

Comment: In my case it was Resharper that had overridden intellisense for TypeScript.