# VS 2015 Angular 2 import modules cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-2015

I have created an empty web project and added files using

> Angular-cli
>
> https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects

I can run the website fine using ng buid/serve but I get below error in editor:

[image]

I read somewhere that it is Resharper error in version 9, so I upgraded my Resharper to latest which fixes the problem but it cannot resolve the modules. any suggestions?

**Edit**: created a new typescript class and it's giving below error

[image]

Comment: Which update of VS 2015 do you have?

Comment: I have installed VS2015 with update 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, Resharper still doesn't support TypeScript latest versions. It looks like Resharper ignores tsconfig.json file that exists inside `src` folder. I suggest you try [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) instead. It's free and has much better support of new TypeScript features.

If you still want to stay with VS 2015, you can configure Resharper not to analyze `.ts` files. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28015409/2586298) is how to do it.

Comment: I will surely try that but it also means i wont be able to use Resharper (Refactor) stuff on ts files?

Comment: Here is a quote of the answer, that I attached above: "This way you still benefit from using Resharper for other files, and you also get the benefits of code formatting and the like for TypeScript using Resharper."

Comment: It actually did the trick, what a shame that Resharper still has not figured this out. I still think VS2015 is a little clunky when it comes to Angular 2 apps.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I suggested using VS Code instead. It is excellent!

Answer (score 0):

open npm and run `npm install typings` and then `typings install` and if after that it still doesn't work, try build the project

Comment: have done everything still giving this weird error for some reason. I believe its a visual studio bug or something

Answer (score 0):

Try installing VS2015 update 3.
I had that error before and I was due to my typescript version installed in VS2015.